# MariaDB 10.9.* for Fedora 39 - CPack Error

Tags: cmake, mariadb, fedora, rpmbuild, cpack

I have updated my linux-server to Fedora 39 and my MariaDB doesn't work now, because old files have been generated for MariaDB 10.9, but after update it auto-install MariaDB 10.5.
What I can do in this case?

I have tried build MariaDB 10.9 from source, but took the error about CPack every time

```
error: File not found: /home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/mariadb-10.9.8-linux-x86_64/s3-engine/etc/my.cnf.d/\*
    File not found: /home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/mariadb-10.9.8-linux-x86_64/s3-engine/etc/my.cnf.d/\*
 ***
CPackRPM:Debug:    - /home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/rpmbuildMariaDB-s3-engine.out
CPackRPM:Debug: *** Building target platforms: x86_64
Building for target x86_64
setting SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=1278201600
Executing(%prep): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.YC5xlh
Executing(%install): /bin/sh -e /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Y0Ko6E
find-debuginfo: starting
Extracting debug info from 2 files
DWARF-compressing 2 files
sepdebugcrcfix: Updated 2 CRC32s, 0 CRC32s did match.
Creating .debug symlinks for symlinks to ELF files
find-debuginfo: done
Processing files: MariaDB-s3-engine-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64

RPM build errors:
 ***
CPackRPM:Debug: GEN_CPACK_OUTPUT_FILES = /home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/RPMS/x86_64/MariaDB-backup-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64.rpm;/home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/RPMS/x86_64/MariaDB-backup-debuginfo-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64.rpm;/home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/RPMS/x86_64/MariaDB-common-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64.rpm;/home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/RPMS/x86_64/MariaDB-common-debuginfo-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64.rpm
CPack: - package: /home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/MariaDB-backup-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64.rpm generated.
CPack: - package: /home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/MariaDB-backup-debuginfo-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64.rpm generated.
CPack: - package: /home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/MariaDB-common-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64.rpm generated.
CPack: - package: /home/fedora/repositories/mariadb/mariadb-build/MariaDB-common-debuginfo-10.9.8-1.fc39.x86_64.rpm generated.
```

Comment: First, as you probably know [10.9](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/release-notes-mariadb-10-9-series/) is EOL. I can't tell what build options you've used, but if you disable S3 it might work `-DPLUGIN_S3=NO`. There is also columnstore build incompatibilities so I'd disable that too `-DPLUGIN_COLUMNSTORE=NO`.  I did manage to build it though there are [cmake/rpmbuild](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-32741) issues that might arise. You can visit [zulip channel](https://mariadb.zulipchat.com/) for realtime help.